# JavaScript のリファクタリングがうまくできません

Tags: javascript

```
const hints = [
    "ロシア連邦",
    "ほうれん草",
    "７９kcal",
    "炒める"
];
```

これらを、window.alertで表示させようとして以下のコードを書きました。

```
const $button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

$button[0].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  window.alert($button[0].textContent = hints[0]);
});
$button[1].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  window.alert($button[1].textContent = hints[1]);
});
$button[2].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  window.alert($button[2].textContent = hints[2]);
});
$button[3].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  window.alert($button[3].textContent = hints[3]);
});
```

このコードをwhile文でループさせてリファクタリングをしようと以下のコードを書き込みました。

```
let hintsIndex = 0;
let hintsLength = $button.length;

while (hintsIndex < hintsLength) {
  $button[hintsIndex].addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    window.alert($button[hintsIndex].textContent = hints[hintsIndex]);
  });
  hintsIndex++;
};
```

リファクタリング前のコードだと正常に機能するのですが、後者のコードではボタンをクリックしてもwindow.alertが出ず、無反応です。
どのようにすれば正常にWindow.alertが出るようになるのでしょうか。お教えいただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こんにちははじめまして
確認させていただきました。

まず **addEventListener** したイベントリスナーですが、これはボタンがクリックされた時に動作するものです。当然ですがループを抜ける前にボタンが押されることはありません。ですので、修正後の例では。**hintsIndex** にこの場合は常に4が入力されています。これでは、配列の長さをオーバーしてますのでundefinedとなり正常に動きません。

ではどうすればいいかですが、とりあえずは、**addEventListener** する前にその中で必要なものをbuttonオブジェクトに格納してしまえばどうでしょうか? これなら参照することに問題はありません。

また、addEventListnerを使ってるのですから、引数eventからボタンオブジェクトを取得しましょう。

```
var hintsIndex = 0;
let hintsLength = $button.length;

while (hintsIndex < hintsLength) {
  $button[hintsIndex].hint = hints[hintsIndex];
  $button[hintsIndex].addEventListener("click", (event)=>{
        window.alert(event.target.textContent = event.target.hint);
    });
    hintsIndex++;
};
```

修正した結果は上記のとおりになります。比較してみてください。

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 2):

このようにすれば alert 表示されるようになると思います。
リファクタリングとして `$button` という変数は複数形の `$buttons` に改名しています。

```
const $buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
hints.forEach((hint, i) => {
  $buttons[i].textContent = hint;
  window.alert($buttons[i].textContent);
});
```